# Sed replace non-commented lines in bash

Tags: bash, sed, rc

I feel I am close to solving this, but can't quite get there.

I have a script that searches to see if a utility is called in `/etc/rc.local`. If it isn't, I want to add a line calling it to the line just before `exit 0` at the end of the file. So far, I have this:

`sudo sed -i 's/.*exit 0.*/'$UTILITY_PATH'\n&/' /etc/rc.local`

This kind of works, but also matches lines with "exit 0" as a comment - which occurs further up `/etc/rc.local` as a reminder to users to ensure that the script should end with this line.

So, to be clear, the following should match:

```
exit 0
 exit 0
exit   0
```

and so forth. The following should NOT match:

```
#exit 0
#     exit 0
#   blah blah "exit 0" blah blah
# exit    0
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: many things to take in mind and many possible outcomes, the best way would be to make the search more specific. one option could be to make your exit like: `exit 0`;    and search specifficaly for that

Comment: @hedgehog I don't have control over the format of the file - it may be user edited and all of those forms of exit 0 are valid to bash

Comment: How about `exit` alone (which depends on the status of the last command) or `exit $((0))` or `x=exit; $x 0` or…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want this:

```
sed -r -i 's/^\s*exit\s{1,}[0-9]/foo\n&/' /etc/rc.local
```

It matches `exit [0-9]` - having possibly space in front and in between.

---

Btw, you can also perform both, the search if the pattern is found and the possible insertion in one step using `awk`:

```
awk '/foo/{m=1}/^\s*exit\s+[[:digit:]]/&&!m{print "foo"}1' /etc/rc.local
```

Newer versions of GNU `awk` also support in place editing:

```
awk -i inplace '/foo/{m=1}/^\s*exit\s+[[:digit:]]/&&!m{print "foo"}1' /etc/rc.local
```

Comment: because he wants to take in mind that this could exists in a comment as well or as text...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - it still matches the commented-out "exit 0" further up in rc.local

Comment: @stefandz Sorry, I missed to anchor the pattern at the begin of the line using `^`. Added that.

Comment: This works very well now and is general enough to allow for modification by others for various situations (including those pointed out by @gniourf_gniourf above.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the awk tip - I need to keep the search and replace separate for this, but might play with it in future. Really need to up my regex game...

Answer (score 3):

This is a question about [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), right? What you want is a match for `exit 0` unless it's preceded by a #. What about this?

```
sudo sed -i 's/^[^#]*exit 0.*/'$UTILITY_PATH'\n&/' /etc/rc.local
```

Comment: That would also match `brexit` ;)

Answer (score 0):

do you have '#' in middle of lane?
bcaus if '#' is the first printable character you are in very easy spot:
use one more regex (which is very simple here) to determine scope of sed operation just smth like this:

```
sed '/^\W*#/ ! s/something_u_want/whatever_u_want/ ' /etc/rc.local
```

`/^\W*#/`  means that sed will apply only for lines mathing this reg-ex, nothing will be done otherwise
and exclamation is just negation so conditions are reversed - now sed will apply only for these lines which DOESNT start from '#'

if # isnt first then... hmmm... maybe:

```
sed '/^[^#]*exit 0/ s/something_u_want/whatever_u_want/ ' /etc/rc.local
```